# Extracting information from svn log

Tags: svn, logging, version-control

Usually when I do an `svn log -v`, I get the response in the format:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r8223 | neo | 2013-04-23 10:51:46 +0200 (Tue, 23 Apr 2013) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /dir/myfile.py

mycomment: validation changes for customers
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But say, I want to list all the revision numbers for svn commits, which have "validation changes" in their comments. How can I list that?

**svn log -l 1000 -v |grep "validation changes"| awk '{print $somevalue}'** 
too doesnt help as it only parts of the comment bit!

Comment: You can do `svn log --xml` to get xml output. You could then pass it off to a python script or whatever you like to parse and search I guess..

Comment: Thanks @Blorgbeard, but I wanted something much simpler other than the option of having to write a tool in python, first to parse, search patterns and format the output. Probably I would go with it ony when there is no other option left

Comment: You're going to have to write a script to parse the log regardless. And doing it with XPath queries will probably be simpler & quicker. If you're manually parsing XML, you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion 1.8+ command-line client allows you can use new `--search` and `--search-and` options with `svn log` command.

The command *does not perform full-text search* inside a repository and considers the following data only:

- revision's author (`svn:author` unversioned property),
- date (`svn:date` unversioned property),
- log message text (`svn:log` unversioned property),
- list of changed paths (i.e. paths affected by the particular revision).

Here is the help page about these new search options:

```
 If the --search option is used, log messages are displayed only if the
 provided search pattern matches any of the author, date, log message
 text (unless --quiet is used), or, if the --verbose option is also
 provided, a changed path.
 The search pattern may include "glob syntax" wildcards:
     ?      matches any single character
     *      matches a sequence of arbitrary characters
     [abc]  matches any of the characters listed inside the brackets
 If multiple --search options are provided, a log message is shown if
 it matches any of the provided search patterns. If the --search-and
 option is used, that option's argument is combined with the pattern
 from the previous --search or --search-and option, and a log message
 is shown only if it matches the combined search pattern.
 If --limit is used in combination with --search, --limit restricts the
 number of log messages searched, rather than restricting the output
 to a particular number of matching log messages.
```

So in your case the command could be:

`svn log -v --search "validation changes" URL-TO-REPOSITORY | awk '{print $somevalue}'`